# How to read Rest API once and make data accessible in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

There are several pages in mobile application written in Flutter - login_page, main_page and other pages. Each page gets its data from Rest API.

Let's say that there is Rest API read method in a page. This method reads 1000+ products from a database. It takes time to generate and transfer data from server to mobile app. I would like to avoid executing this method several times and instead of this run it once and then read the data from memory.

Rest API read method looks as below:

```
class PostListOfProducts {
String? nazwa;
int? kalorie;
int? ig;

PostListOfProducts({this.nazwa, this.kalorie, this.ig});

PostListOfProducts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
nazwa = json['nazwa'];
kalorie = json['kalorie'];
ig = json['ig'];
}
}

class PostListOfProductsAPI {

static Future<List<PostListOfProducts>> getUserSuggestions(String query) async {

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final token = await prefs.getString('token');
final loginEmail = await prefs.getString('dietetyk');
        
Response response = await post(Uri.parse('https://some_page.com'),
headers: <String, String>{
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
},
body: <String, String>{
'loginEmail': loginEmail,
}
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
final List products = json.decode(response.body);

return products.map((json) => PostListOfProducts.fromJson(json)).where((PostListOfProducts) {
final nameLower = PostListOfProducts.nazwa!.toLowerCase();
final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
return nameLower.contains(queryLower);
}).toList();
} else {
throw Exception();
}
}
}
```

the rest of code looks like this:

```
Future<List<PostListOfProducts>> postsFuture = getPosts();
        
static Future<List<PostListOfProducts>> getPosts() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final token = await prefs.getString('token');
final loginEmail = await prefs.getString('dietetyk');
            
Response response = await post(Uri.parse('https://some_page.com'),
headers: <String, String>{
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
},
body: <String, String>{
'loginEmail': loginEmail,
},
        
);
       
if(response.statusCode != 200){
print('Błąd połączenia z bazą danych...  status[${response.statusCode}]');
}
        
final List body = json.decode(response.body);
return body.map((e) => PostListOfProducts.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
    
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
appBar: AppBar(
backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
title: const Text('Nowy produkt'),
actions: [
IconButton(
onPressed: signUserOut,
icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
)
],
),
body: FutureBuilder<List<PostListOfProducts>>(
future: postsFuture,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
} else if (snapshot.hasData) {
return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
}
else {
//print(snapshot.error);
return const Text("Brak danych...");
}
    
},
),
);
}
    
Widget buildPosts(List<PostListOfProducts> posts) {
return Form(
key: _formKey,
child: Column (
children: <Widget> [
    
TypeAheadField<PostListOfProducts?>(
hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide: false,
textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
controller:  _typeAheadController,
decoration: const InputDecoration(
prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
border: OutlineInputBorder(),
hintText: 'Wyszukaj produkt',
),
),
suggestionsCallback: PostListOfProductsAPI.getUserSuggestions,
itemBuilder: (context, PostListOfProducts? suggestion) {
final post = suggestion!;
return ListTile(
title: Text(post.nazwa!),
);
},
noItemsFoundBuilder: (context) => const SizedBox(
height: 50,
child: Center(
child: Text(
'Brak produktów',
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
),
),
),
    
onSuggestionSelected: (PostListOfProducts? suggestion) {
final post = suggestion!;
_name = post.nazwa.toString();
_kcal = post.kalorie!.toInt();
_ig = post.ig!.toInt();
_typeAheadController.text = post.nazwa.toString();

...
    
},
),
```

Could you please advise on how this code could be changed in order to read response from Rest API once and then read data from memory - not from API.

Comment: Consider using the Hive database instead of SharedPreferences. Hive is a robust solution for handling substantial data volumes, offering synchronous operations for optimal performance.

Comment: I would like to store the data in memory. I am not going to store 1000+ records in SharedPreferences

Comment: I think your question needs elaboration. Kindly elaborate on your question.  So that we can help you find a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I have updated the post with more code. Could you please take a look at this and advise how this code could be changed in order to read response from Rest API once and then read data from memory - not from API.

Comment: Okay good job, Now Let me give you an efficient way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a `SingleTon` class where you can store data in a single instance available all over the app.

```
    class ApiDataSingleton {
  List<PostListOfProducts> _products = [];

  static final ApiDataSingleton instance = ApiDataSingleton._internal();

  factory ApiDataSingleton() {
    return instance;
  }

  ApiDataSingleton._internal();

  /// Get product suggestions without calling the API multiple times.
  /// This method fetches product suggestions from the API based on the user's query.
  /// If the suggestions haven't been fetched yet, it retrieves the data from the API.
 
  Future<List<PostListOfProducts>> productSuggestions(String query) async {
    if (_products.isEmpty) {
      // Fetch data from the API if it hasn't been fetched yet
      _products = await PostListOfProductsAPI.getUserSuggestions(query).catchError((e) => throw e);
    }

    // Use data if it's already fetched
    return Future.value(_products.where((e) => e.nazwa!.startsWith(query)).toList());
  }
}
```

Now Here is Your Repository class provided by you.

```
class PostListOfProductsAPI {
  /// Fetch user suggestions from the API.
  /// This method retrieves user suggestions from the API based on the user's query.
  
  static Future<List<PostListOfProducts>> getUserSuggestions(
      String query) async {
    try {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final token = await prefs.getString('token');
      final loginEmail = await prefs.getString('dietetyk');

      Response response = await post(Uri.parse('https://some_page.com'),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          },
          body: <String, String>{
            'loginEmail': loginEmail,
          });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List products = json.decode(response.body);

        return products
            .map((json) => PostListOfProducts.fromJson(json))
            .where((PostListOfProducts) {
          final nameLower = PostListOfProducts.nazwa!.toLowerCase();
          final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
          return nameLower.contains(queryLower);
        }).toList();
      } else {
        throw Exception("Error occurred: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage in AppWidgets

> Note: you can use `ApiDataSingleton` anywhere in your app by calling
> `ApiDataSingleton.instance.productSuggestions("query");` it will return you `PostListOfProducts` without duplicate API callings

Here I have used the method in `TypeAheadField` but you can use it anywhere in an app like the widget `initState` method or `Cubit` Controller in case of using `Bloc`

*I assigned the SingleTon class method `suggestionsCallback: ApiDataSingleton.instance.productSuggestions,` to your Widget instead of Directly using Api `suggestionsCallback: PostListOfProductsAPI.getUserSuggestions,` *

```
TypeAheadField<PostListOfProducts?>(
        hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide: false,
        textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
          controller: _typeAheadController,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            hintText: 'Wyszukaj produkt',
          ),
        ),
        suggestionsCallback: ApiDataSingleton.instance.productSuggestions,
        itemBuilder: (context, PostListOfProducts? suggestion) {
          final post = suggestion!;
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(post.nazwa!),
          );
        },
        noItemsFoundBuilder: (context) => const SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Brak produktów',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onSuggestionSelected: (PostListOfProducts? suggestion) {
          final post = suggestion!;
          _name = post.nazwa.toString();
          _kcal = post.kalorie!.toInt();
          _ig = post.ig!.toInt();
          _typeAheadController.text = post.nazwa.toString();
        },
      )
```

what I did strange to avoid duplicate calling of API.

- Create a SingleTon class where I have stored all my data
- Then I called your Api inside SingleTon and did code to avoid duplication.
- Then I called the Singleton Class method in your Widget

Comment: First of all... thank you for your time and effort.  I tried your changes and it looks that one problem has been solved but another has raised. API is called once (very good - thank you for this) but filter does not work, I mean when I write something in type_ahead box items that are displayed do not change. For instance if I type "bana" I expect "banana" and "banana juice" to be displayed - instead of this full list items is displayed. Is it possible to improve the way that filter works?

Comment: I apologize for the oversight. I just realized that I forgot to include an additional method in the Singleton class. I'm going to update my answer, so please take a look.

Comment: I added _products.where((e) => e.nazwa!.startsWith(query)).toList() to getSuggestion method in singleton class which filter your products based on query locally

Comment: Yes, it works now! Thank you very much for your help and time :)

Comment: Welcome. Always here to help.